# How to slow down the cat command without piping the output to the more command?

Tags: bash, pipe, cat

Bash version 4.4.0
Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Is there a way to slow down the `cat` command to a crawl so I can visually see the output of a file without piping the output into the `more` command or another file?

Comment: piping to the `less` command?

Comment: Using GNU awk's time extension: `cat file | gawk '@load "time";{print;sleep(0.1)}'`

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. General Linux usage questions should be posted to [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) instead.

Comment: Have a look [there](https://superuser.com/a/526249/178656). Try: `perl -pe "system 'sleep .003'" file`

Answer (score 1):

A bash specific approach with command substitution.

```
while IFS= read -rn1 -u9; do printf '%s' "${REPLY:-$'\n'}"; sleep .05 ; done 9< <(help for)
```

If it is a file.

```
while IFS= read -rn1 -u9; do printf '%s' "${REPLY:-$'\n'}"; sleep .05 ; done 9< file.txt
```

---

It looks more like reading while someone is typing.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt cat itself has any parameters that can slowdown display. Script like this probably can :

```
#!/bin/bash 

while read -r i; do echo "$i"; sleep 0.3;done< my-file.txt
```

Comment: That's a reasonable idea but copy/paste that script into http://shellcheck.net and itll tell you about several problems with it that'd need to be fixed to make it usable.